# Is this a bad way to sort a list based on another list's sorted permutation?

Tags: python, list, sorting

**Problem:**

I have a list of lists, `rowData`, that contains other lists in a tabular format, i.e.

```
rowData = [strLabel, intA, intB]
```

I want to sort `rowData` based on the *sum* of the values `intA` and `intB`

So if

```
rowData = [ ['hi', 0, 1], 
            ['how', 0, 0],
            ['ru', 2, 2] ]
```

I'd like to end up with

```
rowData = [ ['how', 0, 0], 
             ['hi', 0, 1], 
             ['ru', 2, 2] ]
```

**Current Solution:**

Currently I have a separate list `sums` that corresponds to the sum of the second and third "columns" corresponding to `intA` and `intB`. My solution:

```
[rowData[i] for i in [sums.index(j) for j in sorted(sums)]]
```

This was the only way that made sense to me after some time searching, but I am confident in its inefficiency and was wondering how inefficient it was in comparison to other (hopefully short) alternatives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass the key argument to the `sort()` and `sorted()` function, using a lambda expression which would define the key upon which the sorting is to be done.

```
rowData = [ ['hi', 0, 1], 
             ['how', 0, 0],
             ['ru', 2, 2] ]

rowData.sort(key = lambda x:(x[1]+x[2]))

print rowData
>>> [['how', 0, 0], ['hi', 0, 1], ['ru', 2, 2]]
```

Or if you want to preserve the contents of `rowData` then you may use `sorted()` in the same way:

```
sortedData = sorted(rowData, key = lambda x:(x[1]+x[2]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using `index` is almost *always* bad, for two reasons:

1. It means you have to do a linear search through `sums` for each value, making your whole algorithm take quadratic time instead of log-linear. For example, if you have 10000 objects, it'll take 100000000 steps instead of about 13288 steps.
2. If means that if you have any duplicate sums, you'll get the wrong results. For example, `[0, 1, 0].index(0)`, `[0, 1, 0].index(1)`, and `[0, 1, 0].index(0)` will give you `0, 1, 0`, not `0, 1, 2`.

In general, the way around this is either `enumerate` or `zip`.

For example, `enumerate(sums)` gives you `(index, sum)` pairs, so you can sort those by the `sums` values with `sorted(enumerate(sums), key=itemgetter(1))`, and you can then use those indices:

```
[rowData[i] for i, value in sorted(enumerate(sums), key=itemgetter(1))]
```

Or you can `zip` together `rowData` and `sums` into `(sum, rowData)` pairs, and then `sorted(zip(sums, rowData))` sorts those pairs by the sums, and then you just extract the `rowData`s:

```
[row for s, row in sorted(zip(sums, rowData))]
```

(Or, alternatively, you could un`zip` the pairs back into two separate lists and just keep the second one.)